# What would be the exact formula for removing and adding these special characters in Excel?

Tags: excel, replace, excel-formula, tags, spaces

Say I have this word(excluding quotes). 
"XE Premium (TT) 2.0T"

I want the above word to show up like this. I am replacing the empty spaces and period with dash.  I am also removing the brackets completely.
"XE-Premium-TT-2-0T"

So far I only know how to do one of those things at a time like this.
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A38)," ","-")

How do I do all of them at the same time in Excel?

Comment: Why can't you do it in 2 steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all at once:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A38)," ","-"),")",""),"(",""),".","-")
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: One more thing. Do you know how can I add comma after each line/cell?

Comment: What I mean is adding commas after each line while maintaining the above format.  I know other wise I can use this to add a comma. =A1&","

Comment: @bigstuff sorry I was away from my desk.  Glad you figured it out.